# Problems with ActionBar Menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I'm trying to re-add an `ActionBar` to an app that previously didn't have one. I've updated the themes to be `Theme.Holo.Light` and re-added the function `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` but now I'm getting an error when trying to run the app due to the following line inside that function

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
```

It's detecting the fault in the `menu` reference, but just suggested changing to R.menu which obviously doesn't do anything in this case. There is a `main.xml` in `res/menu`.

The error being generated is

```
Gradle: cannot find symbol variable menu
```

EDIT:

Here are imports

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
```

EDIT 2:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: You are using ActionBarSherlock? Can you post the imports you are calling?

Comment: @YoannHercouet Not using ActionBarSherlock just now. Posted Imports

Comment: Can you also post the menu/main.xml? I'm suspecting an error in this xml.

Comment: Are you calling `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);` in your `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`? Because menu should be created (inflated) in `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`. `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` is for handling events such as click on menu item.

Comment: @MichałZ. That was it. Can you post as an answer and I'll mark correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);` should be called in `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`. `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` is for handling events such as click on menu item.

Answer (score 0):

I find error because the file name has
res/menu/menu_main.xml
Change it to
res/menu/main.xml

And all work fine!